# Service Worker registration failed with localhost

Tags: javascript, nginx, firefox, localhost, service-worker

So I've been struggling to register a Service Worker on localhost to test its functionality while developing a website. According to the MDN guide for service workers, it states that the code for service workers can only be registered on HTTPS connections, but also considered localhost a secure origin for local development [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#setting_up_to_play_with_service_workers]. However, when I attempt to register it, I get the error

```
DOMException: The operation is insecure. main.min.js:1:310
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/js/main.min.js:1
```

I then tried to HTTPS my localhost connection with a cert made from mkcert and applied the cert with a nginx reverse proxy. After getting that setup I got `https://localhost:8080/` to work and serve the website, but I still get the above error, but with `https://localhost:8080/js/main.min.js:1` listed instead.

So now I'm out of ideas on how to get this registration to work for local development. I am on FireFox if that adds any extra help.

Server Worker Registration Code:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)
    try {
        const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/js/serviceWorker.min.js', { scope: '/' })
        if (registration.installing)
            console.log('Service Worker is installing')
        else if (registration.waiting)
            console.log('Service Worker is installed and waiting')
        else if (registration.active)
            console.log('Service Worker is active')
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
else
    console.log('Service Workers are not supported here. :(')
```

Nginx Config:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen 8080 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        ssl_certificate /Users/soul/localhost.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /Users/soul/localhost-key.pem;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong after testing out the problem in another browser, Safari, as they gave me a better error message. In my registeration code I was doing `{ scope: '/' }`, but since the file was coming from `/js` it wasn't working. Removing that arugment from the `.register` method made it work! And I didn't need to https my localhost.

```
// Failed
const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/js/serviceWorker.min.js', { scope: '/' })

// Worked
const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/js/serviceWorker.min.js')
```